# Google API Path isn't showing

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a path from a JSON file and I can't get the path to show up. There are no errors or indication in the console of why this is. With the exception of the getJSON loop, this code is directly from a [Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple). Something is going wrong when I try to push the new coordinate pair into the array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 3,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        var routeCoordinates = [];

        $.getJSON('Tour_Down_Under_Stage_One.json', function(data) {
          for (var i in data.points) {
              coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(data.points[i].latitude, data.points[i].longitude)
              routeCoordinates.push(coordinates);
          }
        });

        var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: routeCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        route.setMap(map);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what the file looks like. I know that it's parsing correctly because I can console.log the data just fine. It's something with building the array.

```
{
   "points": [
      {
         "distance": 0.0,
         "latitude": -34.964927695699998,
         "longitude": 138.647018457,
         "elevation": 169.94999999999999
      },
      {
         "distance": 0.0,
         "latitude": -34.964927695699998,
         "longitude": 138.647018457,
         "elevation": 169.94999999999999
      },
      {
         "distance": 8.1500000000000004,
         "latitude": -34.964965833400001,
         "longitude": 138.647094732,
         "elevation": 170.0
      },
      {
         "distance": 17.93,
         "latitude": -34.965011598499999,
         "longitude": 138.64718626300001,
         "elevation": 170.06999999999999
      },
      {
         "distance": 27.079999999999998,
         "latitude": -34.965064991299997,
         "longitude": 138.64726253800001,
         "elevation": 170.36000000000001
      },
      {
         "distance": 52.659999999999997,
         "latitude": -34.965213769999998,
         "longitude": 138.64747619299999,
         "elevation": 171.03999999999999
      },
      {
         "distance": 63.43,
         "latitude": -34.965274790300001,
         "longitude": 138.64756772300001,
         "elevation": 172.0
      },
      {
         "distance": 73.459999999999994,
         "latitude": -34.965339666200002,
         "longitude": 138.647644082,
         "elevation": 172.97
      },
      {
         "distance": 84.780000000000001,
         "latitude": -34.965408314000001,
         "longitude": 138.64773561199999,
         "elevation": 173.96000000000001
      }, 

      // LOTS MORE OF THESE //

      ],
   "totalDistance": 138442.46999999991,
   "routeName": "Tour_Down_Under_Stage_One"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is an *asynchronous* function. The JSON data that it fetches is not available after the function returns, where your code is trying to use it. Instead, you need to move this code *inside* the `$.getJSON()` callback, or in a function that this callback calls.

Also, you shouldn't use a `for..in` loop to loop over an array. Either use an old-fashioned numeric `for` loop, or else `.forEach()` or the like.

So, a fixed (but untested) version of the code might look like this:

```
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 3,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        $.getJSON('Tour_Down_Under_Stage_One.json', function(data) {
          var routeCoordinates = [];
          data.points.forEach( function( point ) {
              var coordinates =
                new google.maps.LatLng( point.latitude, point.longitude );
              routeCoordinates.push(coordinates);
          });

          var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: routeCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
          });

          route.setMap(map);
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ax528ha9/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Makes sense. But it looks like you fiddle is in the same spot that we started with. The route isn't showing.

Comment: I got it. I was missing a closing bracket. Any clue on how to get the map to focus on the path on load?